# How to create Object (label, button) using Code

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

How to create Object (label, button) using Code?

Comment: is this about windows forms or ASP.NET?

Comment: VISUAL BASIC .NET -> Want create a label using Code, not Designer (so I can use loop to make a lot of label)

Comment: Snoob, WinForms and WebForms both use VB.NET. The question from M4N remains unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim myButton as new Button  
myButton.width = 100  
myButton.height = 20  
myButton.top = 50  
myButton.left = 50  
Me.controls.add(myButton)
```

Comment: Yes. Given the level of the question, it may be good to also explain where to place this code (in a button click event, for instance, etc.) :)

Comment: @tobiasopdenbrouw, I have answered the question. The code could be placed in many places thats is upto them.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Dim Label1 as New Label()
```

Answer (score 1):

You create you *Label* like every other object, set the properties you need and add it to the *Controls* collection of your form or usercontrol.
I have only a C# example here:

```
var label = new Label
{
    BackColor = Color.DarkGray,
    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
    Width = 60,
};
label.MouseClick += LabelOnMouseClick;

Controls.Add( label );
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: this answer posted before clarification in the original question.

Try information pages such as [HOW TO: Dynamically Create Controls in ASP.NET with Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515). But really: also get a book and study this stuff.

Comment: Snoob's first comment to his original question.